# Determine if swf is in a "debug" player or mode

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging

Is there a way using Flash (CS3+AS3) to determine if the published swf is running in a debug player or in Flash's debug mode?

I'm aware that Flex provides the ability to setup different build targets (release/debug) and that you can use something like `CONFIG::debug` for `#ifdef` style inclusion of code at compile time.

I'm imagining something like `System.isDebug()` but can't find anything. I want to use this because there's debug functionality in my app that I *definitely* don't want to be available in a production environment.

Comment: [Capabilities.isDebugger](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/Capabilities.html#isDebugger)

Comment: Great question. It's important to know this because errors blow up with warnings for the user in the debug player, and there are probably other differences.

Comment: @Antti obsolete link?

Comment: @MattAllegro yeah, that link was posted 10 years ago.. It was to the official docs but i guess that's been taken down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out this class http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/how-to-identify-at-runtime-if-swf-is-in-debug-or-release-mode-build/

This class provides two pertinent (and different) pieces of information:

- Was the SWF built with the -debug switch (has debug symbols compiled in)?
- Is the Flash player a debug player (has the ability to display errors, etc)?

The Capabilities.isDebugger only answers the second question - is the user running the Flash Debug player.  In your case, to gate portions of your application on a debug build, you want the -debug build check (and then don't deliver -debug builds into production).

Note however, that both these checks are runtime checks.  Using conditional compilation (aka CONFIG::debug) around your debug code is still a good idea, as it will ensure that possibly sensitive debug code is NOT delivered in the final SWF, making it as small and secure as possible.

I'm reproducing the referenced code here, in case the blog link ever goes down:

```
package org.adm.runtime
{
  import flash.system.Capabilities;

  public class ModeCheck
  {
    /**
     * Returns true if the user is running the app on a Debug Flash Player.
     * Uses the Capabilities class
     **/
    public static function isDebugPlayer() : Boolean
    {
        return Capabilities.isDebugger;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the swf is built in debug mode
     **/
    public static function isDebugBuild() : Boolean
    {
        var stackTrace:String = new Error().getStackTrace();
        return (stackTrace && stackTrace.search(/:[0-9]+]$/m) > -1);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the swf is built in release mode
     **/
    public static function isReleaseBuild() : Boolean
    {
        return !isDebugBuild();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When it's a Debug Player, your method `isDebugBuild` will always return `false`. My opinion, when the player is a debugger, there is no way to tell if the SWF is a debug or release build.

Comment: @PeterLee It can be a debug player but not a debug build of the swf. A debug build contains line number information in stack traces.